# How to setup System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Have I an application using sqlite...

Ive tried this:

1. installing via ClickOnce Application setup (it works)
2. I Put SQLite.dll file together with .exe in the same folder. (it works}
3. hmm the folder with an .exe only (not working)

What I mean is when you build the project and get the .exe on the folder \bin\Debug and move it somewhere then when you run the app errors will not occurs.

I wondering if there's a way that i can run even without installing ClickOnce Application setup?

I thinking of setup the SQLite.dll on specific path reference? Is it possible to do that?

-thanks

Answer (score 1):

`System.Data.SQLite.dll` is not part of the standard .NET Framework so it does not get installed in the GAC of the client machines when .NET runtime is installed at first.

that's the reason why you should have this dll referenced by your executable, distributed together and in the same folder as your exe is deployed.

or you could distribute it somewhere else like in a sub-folder of your application setup and have proper entries in the configuration file or in the .NET C# code to specify where assemblies not found in the standard locations have to be loaded from.

Comment: I have this.. 

`<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>  ` 
how can i do in specific path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Nuget**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) to get the package installed. For my case, it automatically created 2 subfolders for me, which is x86 and x64, I just followed the folder structure in the bin folder, and it worked fine for my case.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what mean is if you have 2 folders 
-folder1 contains SQLite.dll file together with .exe in the same folder. (it works}

-folder2 contains only .exe (it will not work anymore)

Comment: you can have the answer easily with a google search. The suggest solution to seperate x86 with x64 is to properly maintain the assembly dependency. if you do not do like this, you are likely to encounter some problem, just like your case. why not have a try before asking why? See if it works for you, and then do a Google search?

Comment: the stuff works on me too.. but my problem is when I move or separate the .exe with .dlls stuff it will not work anymore. (I trying to me standalone .exe that can run anywhere)

Comment: Assemblies are components of your Project. Unless you put all the code inside your application you will have to distribute all the parts of your project.